# Optimize join query with need to "filter" for distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

I'm wondering how much more I can optimize a relatively simple query. For abstraction, I only have 2 tables, `albums`, with album_id and album_title and the other is `albums_genre` with album_id and album_genre as columns.

My query is the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT album_title
from albums
INNER JOIN albums_genre
ON albums.album_id = albums_genre.album_id AND (genre = 'Metal' OR genre = 'Jazz')
```

The problem for me is that in the `albums` table 1 id is potentially matched to multiple album titles, I'm trying to find a way to cut down the time needed for distinct since it takes more than half of the overall time. I'm using microsoft DB.

Thanks to everyone in advance!

Comment: Why are you `distinct`ing anyway, perhaps your `join` should be an `exists`? Perhaps the `genre` filter could be converted to `union all`, but without info on indexing it's hard to say. For proper performance help, you need to supply the *full* query, table *and index* definitions (preferably as `create/insert` statements), and share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: Your table setup doesn't sound like it makes sense.  Your albums table should have an album ID, album name, and then have other IDs such as genre ID, artist ID, etc..  The 2nd table "album_genres" would have only an album_genre_ID and a description to go with those genre IDs.  In other words, every table should avoid duplication of information.  By putting album_ID into your genre table, the genre table will end up showing the same genre information repeatedly.  That's an incorrect design.  You might read up on "3NF" here = https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html

Comment: just put an index on genre column and it will work

Comment: FYI "Microsoft DB" could be SQL Server or MS Access - helps to be clear.

Answer (score 0):

a more optimal way is to use `exists` instead of join for your case scenario, you also can use `in` instead of Or for checking multiple values in a column :

```
SELECT album_title
from albums a
where exists ( 
     select 1 from albums_genre g 
     where a.album_id = g.album_id
     and genre in ('Metal', 'Jazz') 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to write the query using `exists`:

```
SELECT a.album_title
FROM albums a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM albums_genre ag
              WHERE ag.album_id = a.album_id AND
                    ag.genre IN ('Metal', 'Jazz')
             );
```

Then for performance, you want an index on `albums_genre(album_id, genre)`.  And index on just `(album_id)` is probably also good enough.

Note that the performance gain comes from removing the aggregation/distinct removal in the outer query.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried your query and it is indeed much fast (about 50%), but it gives me more results compared to my original one. It gives me a bit over 20k rows instead of 19742.

In ```albums``` table, there exist duplicate titles (same title, different album_id) and I think that's what's causing the problem, do you have any ideea how to improve the query?

Comment: @AndreasTzalakas . . . I would argue that this is producing the correct result, because it is producing a separate row for each `album_id`.  However if you really one that `album_title`s to be unique, you can use `select distinct a.album_title`.

Answer (score 0):

Initially the query slowing down was on the 'OR', convert the 'Or' into subquery see below. Instead of distinct use group by

```
SELECT album_title
from albums
INNER JOIN (select album_id from albums_genre where genre in ('Metal' 
,'Jazz'))albums_genre
ON albums.album_id = albums_genre.album_id 
group by album_title
```